# Creating Images on BigCommerce

Tags: json, bigcommerce

Although I can create products in BigCommerce via the API I can't seem to create Images.

The Images is here within the webdav folder

"product_images/uploaded_images/5017289001906.jpg"

So the JSON I am posting to /products/253571/images

is

"{\"image_file\":\"product_images/uploaded_images/5017289001906.jpg\"}"

Every time I get "The field 'image_file' is invalid."

I can't work out what it think is wrong or who to fix it.

Ideas please?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the information provided by the [developer.bigcommerce.com](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/objects/v2/product_image) the information could be either the full URL or the path should be **relative from the import directory**. Check if the mentioned route is correct and if so give a try to the full url like:

> https:// yoursite.tld/images/stuff.png

Comment: Thanks. If i try domain + the path quoted in a browser it returns the image OK. If I use the same thing in the API call I still get "The field 'image_file' is invalid". Ahh, I see whole URL - yes that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but make sure Bigcommerce can access your server.

Check both your `access.log` and `error.log`, if you can't find the GET request to your image by Bigcommerce in both files, try using curl to GET the picture and see if there's a problem.

After hours of failed attempts, I found that my SSL certificate have issues and Bigcommerce is rejecting it by using curl to do a simple GET request.
Fixed my SSL, problem solved!

Bigcommerce should have a more detailed error response.